# CEFSHARP NETWORK EVENT LOG

Tags: logging, networkx, cefsharp

Cefsharp is installed in windowsform project. I am opening different urls in cefsharp.

I want to capture logs from the network log. I used --net-log-capture-mode for this. But I couldn't find where it wrote the log. I don't know where to view it either.

I would be glad if you help.

What I want to do is to display the requests, responses and times as in the devtool Network section.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| --net-log-capture-mode | Sets the granularity of events to capture in the network log. The mode can be set to one of the following values: "Default" "IncludeSensitive" "Everything" See the enums of the corresponding name in net_log_capture_mode.h for a description of their meanings. |

Cesharp code snippet I added;

```
var settings = new CefSettings()
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("net-log-capture-mode", "Everything");
```